# How to reference private types from public functions in private modules?

Tags: module, rust, visibility

I want to group similar functions in a file. Those functions need to return a type which is not public:

```
struct MyStruct;

mod my_mod {
    use super::MyStruct;

    // There are other, similar functions that also return `MyStruct`
    pub fn foo() -> MyStruct {
        MyStruct
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _var = my_mod::foo();
}
```

This fails with the error

```
error[E0446]: private type `MyStruct` in public interface
 --> src/main.rs:7:3
  |
1 |     struct MyStruct;
  |     - `MyStruct` declared as private
...
7 |         pub fn foo() -> MyStruct { MyStruct }
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't leak private type
```

In general, it makes sense not to allow public functions to have private types in their signature, but in this specific case the structure *is* available at the modules root level.

Is there a way to support this without making `MyStruct` public?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a feeling that this error is unwarranted. It should only be an error if `my_mod` is `pub` or if the functions are re-exported in an outer scope.

That said, I found a workaround: move `MyStruct` to a sibling module and make `MyStruct` pub, but not the module.

```
use types::MyStruct;

mod types {
    pub struct MyStruct;
}

mod my_mod {
    use super::MyStruct;

    pub fn foo() -> MyStruct {
        MyStruct
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _var = my_mod::foo();
}
```

Comment: It certainly looks like a bug/limitation, I tracked down https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/30905 which seems to be about the same issue too.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same problem. Rust 2018 seems to have solved it; just refer to the submodule's "public" function as `pub(crate)`, AKA `pub(crate) fn foo()`.

This makes the function only public to the crate: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/more-visibility-modifiers.html