# What exactly is the visibility of an impl block derived from the types used in it?

Tags: rust

I have a crate with a type living inside a module. For internal purposes, I want to implement `ops::Index` for that type with two private index and value types:

```rust
pub mod inner {
    pub struct Data;

    struct Value;
    struct Key;

    impl std::ops::Index<Key> for Data {
        type Output = Value;
        fn index(&self, index: Key) -> &Self::Output {
            unimplemented!()
        }
    }
}
```

This works. So far so good.

But if I change the visibility of `Key` to `pub(crate)`, I get this error ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=93e3bd78625b7dfd532f90a80f910497)):

```
error[E0446]: private type `inner::Value` in public interface
 --> src/lib.rs:9:9
  |
4 |     struct Value;
  |     - `inner::Value` declared as private
...
9 |         type Output = Value;
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ can't leak private type
```

I don't understand this: I thought the "private type in public interface" error was just for the crate-public interface. The same error occurs when moving `Key` to another module.

**Why is the `impl` block suddenly considered a public interface by making `Key` `pub(crate)`? How exactly is the visibility of an `impl` block determined?**

Comment: [How to reference private types from public functions in private modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39334430/155423)

Comment: I think it's because data is public but `impl std::ops::Index<Key> for Data` is private only if key is not public making key public make `impl std::ops::Index<Key> for Data` public but `Value` is private